# Which http code to use when unexpected error on server side?

Tags: http

I know the 5xx codes are used for errors that happened on the server side. I have a function on my server in java where I'm calling another API (the imdb API) inside a try/catch clause. Normally everything should work fine and I will return a 201 status code, that the entity was created. But if something unexpected goes wrong, which can practically only be the case, if the imdb decides to change it's API, then my catch clause will be run and from there I would like to return the stack trace + a proper error code. Which one would you take here?

Comment: What's wrong with 500?

Comment: If you want to follow the standard (you ***really should***!), use 500, you're of course not required to follow the standard (it's ***really recommended*** though), and are free to return any status code with any reason phrase, you can even return `200 OK` with some http error content (like nginx does with it's (for example) `403 Forbidden` status codes, it still returns 403 however), beware that when using 500 clients will most likely display they own error page and completely disregard the content you're sending back